# BigQuery - Large Amount of Rows in Newest Event Table

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I recently linked my Firebase project's Analytics with BigQuery using the free-tier sandbox, and now I'm nearing the 10GB storage ceiling.

I noticed that the majority of that exported data populated to the earliest event table created (earliest table was 6.5GB and other tables were ~50-100MB), so yesterday I just deleted that earliest event table to get rid of all of those old rows I didn't want.

However, I noticed after checking today that the newest event table is roughly the same size as the one I deleted.

My questions are:

- Is the latest table created so big because that's older rows repopulating?
- Is it possible to delete that large chunk of data from storage without a similarly-sized amount flowing into the next event table that's created?